# Error on XML response of a form submit in ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, xml, forms, extjs, response

I am currently upgrading a form to ExtJS 5.
It is supposed to send a request to a webservice that responds in XML. Since ExtJS expects JSON by default, I set up a custom errorReader according to the documentation:

```
errorReader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
    record: 'error',
    success: '@success'
    }, [
        'id', 'msg'
    ]
)
```

Raw response of the server is:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 150
Expires: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 10:00:53 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<message success="false"><errors><error><id>-1</id><msg>FieldMissing</msg></error></errors></message>
```

When the response comes in, I see an error in my page like this (translated from German):

```
Error: Property "scheme" can not be obtained from an undefined or null referenced object
Row: 48503
Source: ext-all-debug.js
```

It happens in an "extractData"-function that does the following:

```
entityType = readOptions && readOptions.model ? Ext.data.schema.Schema.lookupEntity(readOptions.model) : me.getModel(),
schema = entityType.schema,
```

readOptions is undefined, so it does me.getModel() which returns undefined, though I defined a model in the errorReader with id and msg. Then entityType is undefined leading to the error stated above.

I don't understand, what I am doing wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best questions are the ones I can answer myself ;)
It seems like the documentation is wrong or there is a bug in the current implementation.
What the docs said, is just not working:

```
errorReader: new Ext.data.reader.Xml({
    record : 'field',
    success: '@success'
}, [
    'id', 'msg'
])
```

You have to explicitly (not anonymous) define an appropriate model:

```
Ext.define('Field', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'msg']
});
```

... and then assign it in the form:

```
errorReader: new Ext.data.reader.Xml({
    record : 'field',
    model: 'Field',
    success: '@success'
})
```

There seems to be another problem though.. Setting the success property doesn't work at all! I can write 'foo' and it still defaults to 'success', which means it always expects a child of the root instead of an attribute of the root.